# Send a specific signal to an external USB keyboard? Or, how do I fix fdopen()?

Tags: osx, usb

Some background: I'm trying to make the caps lock light on an external keyboard light up on-command when I run a command from the command line. Ideally it would be scriptable, so that I can use it for alerts and things (I disassembled the keyboard).

I got this command which looks like it should work:

```
fd=fdopen("/dev/console"); ioctl(fd, 0x4B32, 0x04);
```

When I try to run this command on either OS X or on a Ubuntu server I have laying around, this happens:

```
me@server1:~$ fd=fdopen("/dev/console"); ioctl(fd, 0x4B32, 0x04);
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
me@server1:~$ fd=fdopen(/dev/console);
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

So it looks like the problem is in the first part. Do I need to install a set of software/utilities? How can I manually control the caps lock light on my external keyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to enter C code into a shell prompt, this doesn't work for obvious reasons.  You could either put it into a correct C file, compile it and get a valid binary you could execute:

```
#include <linux/kd.h>

#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void
usage(char *argv0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <on|off>\n", argv0);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    int on;
    unsigned char state;

    if (argc != 2)
        usage(argv[0]);

    if (strcmp(argv[1], "on") == 0)
        on = 1;
    else if(strcmp(argv[1], "off") == 0)
        on = 0;
    else
        usage(argv[0]);


    fd = open("/dev/console", O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "open /dev/console");

    if (ioctl(fd, KDGETLED, &state) == -1)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "KDGETLED");

    if (on)
        state |= LED_CAP;
    else
        state &= ~LED_CAP;

    if (ioctl(fd, KDSETLED, state) == -1)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "KDSETLED");

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Put this in a file called e.g. `caps.c` and compile it:

```
$ gcc -o caps caps.c
```

Then you can run it as

```
$ ./caps on
```

to turn on the LED or

```
$ ./caps off
```

to turn it off (toggling is left as an exercise for the reader).

**Note:** To open `/dev/console` you'll need super user rights.

**Yet another note:** This also does not prevent your terminal or X server from changing the CapsLock LED occasionally (e.g. when <kbd>Caps</kbd> is pressed).  This also does not work on OS X but only on Linux since there's not standardized way to do this.  Last of all, you *cannot* change LEDs on several keyboards individually.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working - could the keyboard being external play a role?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread that »from the console«.  I'll change the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

That C code would not work anyway -- `fdopen()` requires more than one argument and returns a file stream, not a file descriptor.

I can remember doing this a few years ago, I thought via Xlib, but I could not find my old code (occasionally the collection gets purged) but I figured someone must have a simple app for this on github or something.  Low and behold, the first page I found was [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1372521.html) which while I have no memory of posting it, it was written by me four years ago ("akashiraffee" was a name I used online a lot at the time).

It does not in fact use Xlib -- it uses `ioctl()`, like you were trying to do -- so should work sans GUI.  I tidied it up and tried it here with a 5 LED keyboard:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <linux/kd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

int main (void) {
    int tty = open("/dev/console", 0), led;
    unsigned long int arg;

    if (tty < 3) {
        perror("open: ");
        return -1;
    }

    if (ioctl(tty,KDGKBTYPE, &arg) > 0) perror("ioctl: ");
    if (arg == KB_101) puts("You have a 101 key keyboard.");

    for (led = 1; led < 9; led++) {
        if (ioctl(tty,KDSETLED, led) > 0) perror("ioctl led on: ");
        printf("LED %d on...hit enter", led);
        getchar();
        if (ioctl(tty,KDSETLED, led+0xff) > 0) perror("ioctl led off: ");
        printf("off (hit enter)\n");
        getchar();
    }

    close(tty);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile that `gcc whatever.c -o testleds` then `./testleds` (note **you need superuser privilleges**).  The first 7 worked for me; some of them them were individual LEDs and some of them are combinations.

> I disassembled the keyboard

Of course, you need the ENTER to work to test that.  If it doesn't, leave a comment and I will change to test automatically using a delay instead.  If it does work in the end, I'd be happy to turn it into something you can use to toggle the lights by number (e.g. `toggleLED 3`).

Comment: Enter should still work, as long as I can find which little dot thing used to be ENTER. I'll try this when I get a chance, probably in an hour or two.

Answer (score 0):

### Linux

What you've posted is a snippet of C code. (And not even a working one.) It isn't going to work at a shell prompt.

There is no shell interface to `ioctl`, but you can use Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
require "sys/ioctl.ph";
if (@ARGV) {
    $ioctl = 0x4b32; # KDSETLED
    $ARGV[0] =~ /^[0-8]+$/ or die "$0: $ARGV[0]: invalid argument";
    $arg = int($ARGV[0]);
} else {
    $ioctl = 0x4b31; # KDGETLED
    $arg = "?";
}
sysopen CONSOLE, "/dev/console", "r" or die "$0: /dev/console: $!\n";
ioctl CONSOLE, $ioctl, $arg or die "$0: ioctl: $!\n";
print ord($arg), "\n" unless @ARGV;
```

Or Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import array, fcntl, os, sys
console = open("/dev/console", "r")
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    fcntl.ioctl(console, 0x4b32, int(sys.argv[1])) # KDSETLED
else:
    arg = array.array('B', [0xff]) # KDGETLED
    fcntl.ioctl(console, 0x4b31, arg, True)
    print arg[0]
```

Either program prints the current LED settings if executed with no argument, and changes the LED if passed an argument. The LED settings are expressed as the sum of 1 for Scroll Lock, 2 for Num Lock and 4 for Caps Lock. You can pass the argument 8 to reset the LEDs to correspond to the OS's lock settings.

Instead of calling your own program, you can also call the [`setleds`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setleds) utility from the standard [console tools](http://lct.sourceforge.net/).

You need to either be logged on a text mode console (not under X and not remotely), or to run as root.

### Linux, specific keyboard

You can also turn on and off the LEDs of a particular input device by accessing that device instead of the console device. The ioctl is different: you need to use the [evdev interface](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input-programming.txt) and send [`EV_LED` events](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt).

The easiest way to use this interface is to install the [`evdev`](https://pypi.org/project/evdev/) Python package (`pip install evdev`).

```
</dev/input/by-id/usb-_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd \
python -c 'import evdev; dev = evdev.InputDevice("/dev/stdin"); print dev.leds()'
```

See “Getting and setting LED states” in the [tutorial](https://pythonhosted.org/evdev/tutorial.html) for more examples.

### OSX

On Mac OS X, you can access the keyboard LEDs through the [HID interface](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/intro/intro.html). You can find examples and explanations [in *Mac OS X Internals*](https://web.archive.org/web/20200103161737/http://osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter10/kbdleds/) or on [*Psychic Origami*](https://www.psychicorigami.com/2009/03/01/5k-morse-code-app-using-capslock-led/).